Energy estimate for the harmonic map heat flow
I am working through Struwes paper "On the evolution of harmonic maps in higher dimensions" (https://projecteuclid.org/journals/journal-of-differential-geometry/volume-28/issue-3/On-the-evolution-of-harmonic-maps-in-higher-dimensions/10.4310/jdg/1214442475.full)  and am stuck at the energy estimate in Lemma 3.1. The proof there is not written in detail, but I could reconstruct most of it. However, I am still not getting why the boundary terms vanish.
Let $u\colon \mathbb{R}^n \times [0,T] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ (for simplicity assume just $\mathbb{R}$ as the targetmanifold) be a solution to the heat equation $(\partial_{t}-\Delta)u=0$ . Then, we can multiply the heat equation by $\partial_{t}u$ or equivalently by $\Delta u$ and integrate by parts (using Green's first identity) to obtain
$$ 0 = \int_{B_{r}(0)} \Delta u (\partial_{t} u-\Delta u) \text{d}x 
= -\int_{B_{r}(0)} \langle\nabla u ,\nabla(\partial_{t} u-\Delta u)\rangle \text{d}x + \int_{\partial B_{r}(0)} \langle \nabla u, N\rangle (\partial_{t} u-\Delta u) \text{d}S , $$
where $N$ denotes the normal vector. The last integral is again equal to $0$, since $u$ is a solution of the heat equation.
Furthermore, we calculate
$$\int_{B_{r}(0)} \langle\nabla u ,\nabla(\partial_{t} u-\Delta u)\rangle \text{d}x = \frac{1}{2} \partial_{t} \int_{B_{r}(0)} |\nabla u|^2 \text{d}x - \int_{B_{r}(0)} \langle \nabla u, \nabla\Delta u\rangle \text{d}x ,$$
and again use Green's first identity for the second integral to obtain
$$\int_{B_{r}(0)} \langle \nabla u, \nabla\Delta u\rangle \text{d}x = - \int_{B_{r}(0)} |\Delta u|^2 \text{d}x + \int_{\partial B_{r}(0)} \langle \nabla u, (\Delta u)N \rangle \text{d}S .$$
Here, I do not see, why the boundary term vanishes.
The rest of the proof follows by taking the limit $r\rightarrow \infty$ and integrating from $0$ to $T$.
A similar result is given in "The analysis of harmonic maps and their heat flows" by Lin and Wang in Lemma 7.5.2 (page 176). Again without a detailed proof. So I feel like I am missing something "obvious" here. Understanding these will help me in showing similar results for higher order PDEs (e.g. 4th order).
Thanks already,
Nils

Maybe $u, \nabla u, \Delta u$ decay to $0$ at $\lvert x \rvert \rightarrow \infty$, which is normal behavior for the heat equation (at least as long $u_0$ decays at $\lvert x \rvert \rightarrow \infty$)

@HyperbolicPDEfriend
Struwe is also assuming $\int_{\mathbb{R}^n} |\nabla u|^2 \text{d}x < 0 $ for all $t$. Would this be sufficient to have decay to $0$ of said functions?
